How to Accurately Measure Current for LED Groups Driven by multiple PWM on STM32?
I am using 8 PWM ports on an STM32 to drive 8 different LED groups, with a PWM frequency of 1 kHz. I want to measure the current flow for each LED group. However, due to the varying duty cycles of the PWM signals, accurately measuring the current is challenging.
What is the best way to measure the current for each port in this scenario? Thank you in advance for your answers!

Hi, would you like to measure current in "circuit" to be used somewhere else or just externally with a multimeter for example?

Hi, I want to measure current via STM32. In design there is shunt resistor but it's still hard to get ADC value due to PWM frequency and multiple PWM usage so far.

Can you share a schematic of the circuit?

How accurate does the current measurement need to be? Is the software in the STM32 intended to use the current measurement to adjust the PWM duty cycle in some way?

Do you want to measure the instantaneous or RMS current?

@ChesterGillon I'm going to log current consumption periodically for two reasons. First is monitoring current consumption for each port and second one is if LED strips are working properly or not.

@DirceuRodriguesJr I think RMS current is reasonable for the application I mentioned in the comment above.

@BurakBerzener Suggest you [edit] the question to include the information about the requirements for logging current consumption, as questions are supposed to contain all information needed to answer.
